# Delaying a startup program using regedit

Tags: boot, regedit, delay

i am looking to delay a program at startup for 2 mins, i know there are startup programs out there but need a registry tweek as i need then to push it out as a GPO to 200 machines. can anyone advise if this can be done and if so how and where!?!
thanks

Comment: Do you have to use the registry or will any built-in windows thing (Namely, task scheduler) work?

Comment: It would help if you told us what program you were trying to delay at startup.

Comment: it is a non windows program

Answer (score 1):

Try using this trick as the command to start your application. For instance, if you were starting Notepad.

```
ping -n 1 -w 120000 1.1.1.1 || C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe
```

- **-n 1** — signifies to send only one packet.
- **-w 120000** — means to wait 120,000 milliseconds (2 minutes) for the packet.
- **1.1.1.1** — is a reserved IP address that will never resolve.
- **||** — means OR, and will wait for the first program to finish, then execute the second.

Other options include:

- Writing a batch script, or VBScript to pause and then execute your program and adding the script to the startup instead.
- Using [GPO to push out a scheduled task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx) configured to start at logon with a delay.

Comment: think i've found it
the service was located in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services and there was an dalayedautostart registry in there under the service i needed. modified it and pushed nee registry out over GPO.
all seems good thanks

Comment: @david, it would have been helpful to know the program was an installed service.